# integrating dropbox with ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, dropbox

I want to integrate Dropbox into my ionic app. The functionality I need is when I click on dropbox icon I should able to open the Dropbox app and transfer the file from Dropbox to ionic. Do anyone have resources for this?

Answer (score 1):

The Dropbox API has a component for this, named as a **Chooser**.
See the [Dropbox API doc here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser#javascript).

What is Chooser :

> The Chooser is the fastest way to get files from Dropbox into your web
>   app. It's a small JavaScript component that enables your app to get
>   files from Dropbox without having to worry about the complexities of
>   implementing a file browser, authentication, or managing uploads and
>   storage.

How to use it :

- Import the Dropbox library
- Trigger the Chooser with a button (and set it up with some options)
- Handle the response (which is an array of file objects, given by the success callback function)

Comment: Links are fantastic, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedbacks, I'm new to Stackoverflow. I edited it to add more infos :)